# How autocomplete a PowerShell command in history?

Tags: powershell

In VSCode PowerShell, when I type a command (say myprogram), it prompts me with a history in gray colored text, like below:

```
myprogram 'c:\path\to\file' -someopt
```

But TAB seems not working here. What keyboard shortcut should I use here to autocomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right arrow key completes the command.